# Parsing error in a function in a reactjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been making a small reactjs app and I'm getting parsing error in the function.

this is the error that I'm getting

```
  Line 104:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  102 | //       });
  103 | //     });
> 104 | analysis(){  
      |           ^
  105 |   fetch('/api/analyse', {
  106 |       method: 'POST',
  107 |       body: JSON.stringify({
```

This was the function I've put above render method. I've used a function instead of componentDidMount because there are multiple functions that'll get invoked when I click the analyse button. This is just one of those function and every functions have this same parsing error.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

handleRequest = async () => {
  const post = this.state;

  const request = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  if (postId != null) {
    post["id"] = postId;
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch("/api/updateposts", {
      ...request,
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    });
    const data = await response.json();

    if (data.status === 200) {
      console.log("success", "post saved successfully!");
    } else {
      console.log(
        "danger",
        "An error has occured while updating the post. Please try again"
      );
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    console.log(
      "danger",
      "An error has occured while updating the post. Please try again"
    );
  }
};

handlePost = () => {
  if (postId == null) {
    return handleRequest("/api/savepost");
  }
  return handleRequest("/api/updatepost");
};

analysis(){  
  fetch('/api/analyse', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        snippetdesc: 'snippetDescription'
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then((textdata) => {
        this.setState({
          textdata : textdata.data,
          textlen : snippetDescription.split(' ').length
        });
      },(error) => {
            console.log(error)
      })
  }

export default class MainText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      id: null,
      snippetDescription: "",
      textdata: [],
      textlen: 0
      loadingautocorrection: true;
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
               <Button
                  className="btn savebtn"
                  onClick={() => handlePost({ ...this.state })}
                >
                  Save <i className="fas fa-save" />
                </Button>
      </>
)}
```

Comment: The answer lies in your previous function. Perhaps you're not closing everything correctly?

Comment: have a look at the edited post, I added the previous function too. I think I've closed everything

Comment: Should I put it inside the 'export default class Text extends Component'? functions can be outside the class, right?

Comment: Where is this `analysis` construct? Is it in a `class` or on its own?

Comment: in it's own. not inside class. should i put it inside class? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @henrydoe - We'd need more context. Without `function` in front of it, that's method syntax, which is only valid in a class or an object literal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added the whole component now, You can see how I have structured it. can you understand now where the error is coming from?

Comment: @henrydoe - **Don't** edit the question to incorporate answers. It makes the question unclear and the answers look like they just repeat the question. I've edited the `const analysis = () => {` back to `analysis() {` as it was in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to put the `function` keyword before the function name:

```
function analysis() {
... 
}
```

or

```
const analysis = () => {
...
}
```

Comment: Or use `const analysis = () => { ...`

Comment: yeah adding this have removed that error, now I'm getting other errors. anyway I think your solution worked. thank you @FrankerZ

Comment: @henrydoe - Questions aren't supposed to be moving targets. You asked about a specific problem, which the answer above shows you how to correct. If you a more general problem writing a React component, then look closely at several examples and tutorials, and **if** you still can't figure it out, post a question with the details of what you're trying to do, what you've looked at, and what problem you're having.